# Custom Camera : Picture size small

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I'm working on custom camera. So, When I capture image from **native camera**, it's **size** is **1.76MB**. But, when I capture it from **Custom Camera** it's **977.86KB**. I've set following properties to camera...

```
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();         
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        parameters.setPictureSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        parameters.setRotation(90);
        parameters.setJpegQuality(100);
        parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);

        android.util.Log.i(TAG, "####### setting FLASH_MODE_TORCH");
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        parameters.setFocusMode("continuous-picture");

        if (parameters.getSupportedFocusModes().contains("continuous-picture")) {
            parameters.setFocusMode("continuous-picture");
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "FOCUS MODE continuous-picture NOT SUPPORTED......!!!");
        }

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
```

> So, where is the problem? Is there any property/Parameter that I'm missing but need to set to camera in order to get expected outcome??

Answer (score 0):

You set the picture size to preview size. It's not only small, it may even cause a RuntimeException.

Camera.Parameters have a separate [`getSupportedPictureSizes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes()) method. You should choose one of these supported picture sizes, and except for some very few very weird cases, this will work.

Same is true for the preview size. Pick the one that fits your expectations best from the list returned by [`getSupportedPreviewSizes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes()). Also, note that some sizes are supported only by front camera, and some - only by rear-facing camera. Which means, you call `getSupportedPictureSizes()` *after* you switch from rear to front.

Comment: I've handled now for that getSupportedPreviewSizes() checking for rear and front camera. But, I want result where this big difference of (1.76MB - 977.86KB) should be resolved and for custom camera also image should be of 1.76MB....??

Comment: So, you have correct image resoultion, but the size of the JPEG is too small? This could be caused by auto-focus, or white balance, or HDR, or effects (even though all standard effects e.g. [EFFECT_SEPIA](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#EFFECT_SEPIA) _reduce_ the image size).

Comment: **Yes, I've correct image resoultion now,** but the size of the JPEG is too small? I've implemented auto-focus but **how to maintain image size to 1.76MB as per native camera even if I'm implementing auto-focus functionality????**

Comment: If you take twp pictures in controlled environment (better indoors) with your app and with the stock camera app - do you see difference in image quality? File size is a very indirect measure of this quality).

Comment: Look at the EXIF header of the better image. It may contain information about the ISO, exposure, focus, and other settings. You may send me two images, I would like to have a look, too.

Comment: How to get that EXIF header??? But, actually I've taken both images i.e., from native and custom camera on desktop and checked properties of both , it also gives me more description of that image... and it says that image size issue???

Comment: _`and it says that image size issue??`_ who says what?

Comment: What I'm trying to describe you is that after viewing properties of both images (taken on desktop) by right clicking them, it shows size as 977.86KB for Custom Camera Image and for native camera Image, it's 1.76MB...???

Comment: I still cannot understand why this size matters so much. It may correlate with [image quality](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_quality), or not.

Comment: You could pad the image with zeros to achieve the desired size ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58412/discussion-between-ricky-and-alex-cohn).

Comment: Sorry, I am not online now. If you want to convince me that the custom camera image is not good enough, you can send the two photos to me to compare.